# Как сделать маску номер телефона с MaterialUi

Tags: css, reactjs, input, material-ui

Нужно сделать маску на `TextField` по формату телефона `+380 99 999 9999` Перебрал все способы и не нашел самого подходящего. Как сделать маску без танцов с бубнами ? И я так понял что в компонентах MaterialUi нельзя сделать маску по дефолту

```
                    <form className={classes.form} onSubmit={loginHandler}>
                <TextField
                    onChange ={(e)=>setFormData({...formData, username: e.target.value})}
                    variant="outlined"
                    margin="normal"
                    required
                    fullWidth
                    id="username"
                    label="Номер телефона"
                    name="username"
                    autoComplete="username"
                    autoFocus
                />
               

                <TextField
                    onChange = {(e)=>setFormData({...formData, password: e.target.value})}
                    variant="outlined"
                    margin="normal"
                    required
                    fullWidth
                    name="password"
                    label="Пароль"
                    type="password"
                    id="password"
                    autoComplete="current-password"

                />

                <Button
                    type="submit"
                    fullWidth
                    variant="contained"
                    color="primary"
                    className={classes.submit}
                >
                    Войти
                </Button>

                </form>
```

Comment: В `Textfield` вы  такое не сделаете в MUI. Могу посоветовать npm пакет

Comment: да,использовал пакет material-ui-phone-number,самая лучший вариант

Answer (score 0):

Использовал пакет [material-ui-phone-number](https://www.npmjs.com/package/material-ui-phone-number)

```
<MuiPhoneNumber
    defaultCountry={'ua'}
    variant="outlined"
    margin="normal"
    required
    fullWidth
    id="username"
    label="Имя"
    name="username"
    autoComplete="username"
    autoFocus
    onChange ={(e)=>setFormData({...formData, username: e})}
/>
```